# After Kentico Upgrade 8.2 to to 9 site throwing System.Web.WebPages.Razor version , Version=2.0.0.0, exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, upgrade, kentico

I am upgrading Kentico website from 8.0 to 10.0.
From 8.0 -> 8.1,8.1 -> 8.2 it went smoothly.
After upgrading from 8.2 to 9.1 site throwing error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have excluded the CMSApp_MVC.csproj,CMSApp_MVC.csproj.user files also as mentioned in Documentation.

I tried with NuGet package update command but no use.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' on version '2.0.0.0' is installed? Have you checked it on file system? (bin folder). I would also suggest cleaning solution and installing everything from scratch

Comment: Yes, I have checked reference DLL is available in the bin folder

Comment: well, you don't specify full stacktrace so all I can say is - .NET compiler disagrees with you

Answer (score 0):

Perform below steps and after check the below URL for system requirement.

1. Clearing out "temporary asp.net files" from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
2. Restart the Application pool from IIS

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/installation/server-and-hosting-requirements

Answer (score 0):

Change the .net version to 4.5 (or 4.6)